# Help decoding line code

Tags: rf, signal-processing, sdr, fsk

I have collected a burst signal from a radio device using an RTL-SDR and gnuradio and demodulated the FSK, but am having trouble deciphering what the line code is.

Signal is at 151.3MHz

Here is the signal in inspectrum
[image: Signal in inspectrum]

Here is the signal zoomed in
[image: Zoomed in signal]

You can download the [raw captured burst](https://foxdogstudios.com/static/gnuradio/burst-3.raw). I am viewing it using [inspectrum](https://github.com/miek/inspectrum). Also available is the [demoded signal](https://foxdogstudios.com/static/gnuradio/burst-1-demod-cut.raw)

I'm expecting around 12 bytes, after the preamble, that are transmitted from a sensor (that is from a third party).

Comment: Telling which **frequency** band or better exact frequency you was recording would help a lot!

Comment: Are you searching for aliens?

Comment: @Curd I've updated the post to include the frequency

Comment: @Andyaka I'm searching for 12 bytes.

Comment: @ElDog: Do you know the purpose (source and intended receivers) of the signal? f ≈ 151MHz is used e.g. for radio controlled traffic lights in Germany (maybe in other places too). If you know exactly what signal it is you may find information about how it is encoded.

Comment: It just means "101100101100100101101100100100101100101100101101100100101100101010101011001100". Where's the problem?

Comment: @Curd the high low state encodes a bit, e.g., 101 could be 1 and 100 could be a zero, depending on the line code used, see figure 4. in https://greatscottgadgets.com/tr/gsg-tr-2016-1.pdf

After the preamble I'm expecting to read around 12 bytes as I believe it to be a reading from a sensor.

Comment: Yes, of course. A bit can be **anything**. What I want to say is: you need to give/obtain more information. We can do only a limited about of intelligent guessing but not clairvoyance.

Comment: So why don't you answer the quesion I asked above: Do you know the purpose (source and intended receivers) of the signal?

Comment: Make a simple bi-phase Decoder and extra the data or send to UART if you know how (search if you don’t)

Comment: Kind of looks like Manchester NRZ coding?

Comment: @KingDuken: obviously it is not Manchester code (just looking at the first 15 bits); you needed a bit change (0→1 or 1→0) either after every even or after every odd bit positions. At odd positions it doesn't work after bit3. At even positions it doesn't work after bit14.